# Computer freezes and won't boot again

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, boot, freeze

I'm using (or rather, have used) a desktop with Ubuntu 16.04 running on an SSD. A few days ago while I was using it, it froze. That is, I could only move the mouse but not click on anything. A red led below the computer's power button turned on - I think it's the disk one. Anyway, I restarted it and it wouldn't allow me to boot, sometimes not recognizing the drive at all, and at other times only booting to shell and showing messages regarding bad sectors.

I immediately backed up everything important and went to the store to buy a new hard drive. I installed a fresh Ubuntu on it, thinking the problems were behind me. However, two days after, same thing happened again: froze while I was using it, red led went on - and now it won't boot again and I can't even get to the shell.

Could my computer / home electricity be damaging hard-drives? Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Have you tried plugging the SSD into a different SATA port on your motherboard and using a new SATA cable?

Comment: "Could my computer / home electricity be damaging hard-drives?" - No; This isn't happening.

Comment: "Any ideas what's going on?" - You need to determine what the LED turning on means, we cannot tell you what it means, we don't have enough information to even make an educated guess what it means.